# popup alert going off the screen when resizing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css

I have a popup box that is displayed when the user moves the mouse on an icon.  The css for the hover is as follows :-

```
.profile-bubble {
background-color: #EDEDED;
border: 2px solid #666666;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 1.3em;
margin: 0.6% 2% 2% 90%;
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
width: 150px;
opacity: 0.9;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888888;
```

}

This works fine, however the problem is that when I resize the screen, or if the user has a smaller resolution than I do, then the alert box goes out of the screen.

How can I amend this css to make it proportionate the the size of the screen?

Thanks for your help and time.

UPDATE------------------------------------------------------
this is the header css:-

```
/* Header*/
```

header {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

```
#headerContainer {
height: 33px;
background-position: 10px 2px;
padding-top: 2px;
```

}

```
.headerProfileNotifications {
float: right;
padding-right: 4px;
margin: 3px;
position: relative;
```

}

```
.headerProfilePhoto {
float: right;
position: relative;
margin: 3px;
```

}

```
img {
border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
```

}

```
img {
border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
```

}

```
img:hover {
border: 2px solid #000000;
```

}

```
.headerProfileDetails {
float: right;
padding-right: 4px;
font-size: 11px;
text-align: right;
```

}

```
.headerProfileName {
margin-top: 2px;
```

}

```
.headerProfileEmail {
clear:both;
float:right;
margin-top: 0px;
```

}

and the html:-

```
<header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div id="headerContainer">
                <div class="headerProfileNotifications">
                        <img src="Images/" alt="notification" />
                </div>
                <div class="headerProfilePhoto">
                        <img src="Images/" alt="profile_photo" />
                </div>
                <div class="headerProfileDetails">
                    <div class="headerProfileName">
                            John Smith
                    </div>
                    <div class="headerProfileEmail">
                            john.smith@somemail.co.uk
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Are you adding positioning in JS, because I see you have it set to position absolute, but there's no top/left/bottom/right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the width and height a percentage too -

```
width:50%;
height:50%;
```

And make the box-sizing to border-box so that you don't have to account for margin,padding,etc. and it all comes into the width only.

And then position it accordingly(you have `position:absolute`) -

```
top:20%;
left:20%;
```

Your image and bubble has to be inside a container with no other elements inside the container.
See this [example on codepen.](http://codepen.io/saivineet89/pen/aoiCw)

This container has to be positioned relative.

Comment: I did put percentage and although it looks better now, its still not aligned properly under the image.

Comment: I tried right: 0; and top: 5%, which is the best position to be in, however still not aligned properly when resized

Comment: Is the image that you want this bubble to be aligned to has position:static? It has to be anything other than that or else position:absolute wont work.

Comment: I have the following css for the image:-  .headerProfilePhoto {
    float: right;
    height: 33px;
    width: 22px;
    margin: 5px;
}

Comment: still no luck :-  .headerProfilePhoto {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

Comment: I added the html and the CSS so the question will be more understandable and clear

Comment: thanks for the example Vineet, it helped me solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `left` and `top` property in css:

```
.profile-bubble {
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    border: 2px solid #666666;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    margin: 0.6% 2% 2% 90%;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888888;
    left:25%; //<-------------------------------add this
    top:25%;  //<-------------------------------and this
 }
```

Comment: I tried right: 0; and top: 5%, however still not aligned properly